# Combine web component with 3rd party web component libraries

Tags: css, web-component, svelte

I've been trying to find a web component framework that allows you to integrate 3rd party web components so that dev won't have to spend time writing CSS when they can reuse libraries such as material component web.

I've checked out svelte, lit-element, and stenciljs but they all run into issues when trying to integrate with 3rd party web components. Are there underlying reason that web component might be incompatible with nesting 3rd party web components?

Update:
I am running into an issue where web components exist in the dom but not visible to users when built.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Svelte + TS + Vite App</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs@2.6.0/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons&display=block" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="module" src="./assets/MatButton.wc.0e5949a7.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <my-mat-button></my-mat-button>
  </body>
</html>
```

It renders correctly in dev but I am looking to share the component for users to embed via script.

In dev:

[image]

In /dist:

[image]

All other components work correctly except for the web component.

Comment: What issues have you run into? Web components should be framework agnostic — e.g. a WC built with Svelte should be able to be used in a Lit WC without issue.

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood what I was using. MDC-W totally works. It's SMUI that runs into issues where either styles are missing or errors. Thanks!

Comment: @GeoffRich I've updated the question from recent issue.

Comment: Again, the error/misunderstanding was on my end. `main.ts` imports aren't included for the built output for `/dist`. To fix this I should import web components directly in the svelte component. Everything works now.